# Azure Functions - Return values with no output bindings? Is this possible?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm a newbie to Azure Functions, and i have written an Azure function to create a new resource for me in Azure . The function returns an Id wrapped in a type ive created.

The main reason for this is that i have written integrations tests that does some checks and teardown process based on the Id returned from the function.

```
 [FunctionName("SomeAzFunction")]
        public async Task<MyNewReturnType> Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("%topic-name%", "some-subscription", Connection = "service-bus-connection-string")]
            string message,
            ILogger log)
```

However When deployed, i'm  getting this following error. Is it mandatory to have a output bindings if an Azure function has return values? Or am i approaching Azure functions incorrectly?

```
Function (SomeAzFunction) Error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'SomeAzFunction'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter '$return' to type MyNewReturnType&. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
```

Comment: It only to verify my integration test first and foremost, so i don't need a return value. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think you are approaching this slightly wrong.

So you have a function that is consuming messages from your Service Bus. 
You do some processing and then you are returning a value, where do you expect it to be returned? 
If you want to place a message back on the service bus then you can use a Service Bus Output binding, see available bindings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#supported-bindings).

Or you could create a `SubscriptionClient/TopicClient` and publish a message manually to that subscription/topic.

If you are only returning a value for your integration tests to verify, then I suggest you move that code into a separate class that you function calls and test that.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that. it was to support my integration test so i will remove the return value.

Comment: If you move your logic into a separate class you can then just unit test that class